# Error when importing pynotify

Tags: application-development, pygtk

When i add

```
import pynotify
```

and try to run my app i get

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gobject/constants.py:24: Warning: g_boxed_type_register_static: assertion `g_type_from_name (name) == 0' failed
  import gobject._gobject
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: specified class size for type `PyGtkGenericCellRenderer' is smaller than the parent type's `GtkCellRenderer' class size
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

with another example i don't get the error...

Comment: The warning messages are not pynotify errors, but GTK warnings. Can you please paste more of your code?

Comment: you can see all the code here https://github.com/Clepto/MangaR/blob/master/mangar/MangarWindow.py ...
the problem occurs only when i uncomment the import pynotify. The function about notify is last

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only use pynotify if you are using Gtk2.  If you are using Gtk3 (which is the default for Quickly), you would use `from gi.repository import Notify`.

Comment: do i have to change anything in the show_notification function in the end of the code? because i get: 
  File "/home/chris/Projects/MangaR/mangar/mangar/MangarWindow.py", line 617, in show_notification
    n = Notify.Notification(title, body)
TypeError: GObject.__init__() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)

Comment: i push the code in github! https://github.com/Clepto/MangaR/commit/52d21de49a7307ae4af3db37f36ca5bcf78e0eb8